# sort - prepend each group that start with the same letter in sorted list with an arbitrary string

Tags: bash, shell, sorting, awk

Given the following list (input):

```
apple
banana
blueberry
mango
melon
```

I want the following output:

```
== A ==
apple

== B ==
banana
blueberry

== M ==
mango
melon
```

Is this possible to do in a shell script, perhaps with `awk` or some other text processing utility?

**Additional assumptions**:

1. In this case, assume that we'll be piping the input into `awk` like so:

   `cat input | awk ...`
2. (optional) The text stream contains non-standard characters (non-ASCII) such as Japanese, Arabic and also contains numbers and special symbols. Perhaps these can be grouped together in their own category (would require additional logic).

Comment: possible, yes.. did you try anything?

Comment: I'm not familiar with writing logic into `awk`, can you provide an example of your suggestion? Other tools are also ok, doesn't have to be `awk`. I've checked `man sort` but it doesn't seem to be supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this `awk`:

```
awk '{s = substr($0, 1, 1)} 
    s != p {print "===", toupper(s), "==="} {p = s} 1' file
```

```
=== A ===
apple
=== B ===
banana
blueberry
=== M ===
mango
melon
```

**`awk` details:**

- `{s = substr($0, 1, 1)}`: Save first character of each record in variable `s`
- `s != p`: If `s != p` (`p` is variable to hold previous record's first character)
- `{print "===", toupper(s), "==="}`: Print record separator with uppercase `s`
- `{p = s}`: Save `s` in `p`
- `1`: Print each record

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to write it on one line and assume that we're piping to awk from the standard output stream? I'm trying to get this to work but having some issues..

Comment: The input is passing through unchanged, with the exception of the first line containing `=== ==`

Comment: `cat input | awk '{s = substr($0, 1, 1)} s != p{print "===", toupper(s), "==="} {p = s} 1'` is one line and you can pipe through any output.

Comment: `awk '{s = substr($0, 1, 1)} s != p{print "===", toupper(s), "==="} {p = s} 1' ./output-uniq-items.txt | less -MRI` doesn't work as intended.

Comment: please clarify `doesn't work as intended`. It works with the same data provided as you can see in attached output.

Comment: Ok sorry, it seems to work with the given example but not with a file that I actually want to use it on, so I'll have to investigate further. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Sorry the issue was entirely on my end.
I was forcing color from grep throughout the processing so I had to strip ANSI escape (color) codes to make it work.
`sed -r "s/\x1B\[([0-9]{1,3}(;[0-9]{1,2})?)?[mGK]//g"`

Thanks for your help, still some processing needs to be done but now it's working as intended! Accepting your answer.

Comment: @PetrusK. You don't need grep when you're using awk and you certainly don't need to add a call to sed to modify the grep output before passing it to awk!

Comment: The color codes were tagging along from an earlier call to a shell script which executes `grep -ri --color=always ...`, it's sorted now, thanks. If you know of a way to tell awk to filter out (ignore) any color codes then I could omit the posted sed command. Either way, it works fine.

Comment: `sed -r 's/foo//g' | awk '{bar}'` = `awk '{gsub(/foo/,""); bar}'`